# Rinsing grapes before harvest...how to best do it

Tags: wine

I would like to rinse my grapes before making wine this year. I do understand that I may lose a little flavor, the main reason I would like to do it is to get rid of the fungicide I used during the year, I really do not want to drink it. The question is....1) Can I rinse them with a hose on the vine 1-2 days before harvest? or 2) Harvest and then rinse them on the plastic container, let them dry and crush them. Thank you very much, Roger

Comment: You should carefully adhere to the fungicide safety leaflet.  Rinsing will not remove the harmful chemicals - only the vine will in the window period indicated.

Answer (score 2):

I always rinse my harvested grape clusters manually in a big bucket of water with metabisulfite.

This gives me a bit of control:

- It is easier to remove insects, not much, but e.g. earwigs
- It is easier to remove rotten or otherwise not healthy grapes
- When rinsed, I can then immediately pull the grapes from the stalks and add them to another bucket for pressing later

It is a bit of work, but then I only harvest grapes for about 10 litres of juice.